# Highcharts: Can I add a line on top of a heatmap programmatically?

Tags: highcharts

I have a very large heatmap with a 100x100 grid of data in a chart.

**I don't want to display the legend on this chart.**

I would like to be able to programmatically, with Javascript, add another line on top of the heatmap whenever a user clicks a specific checkbox on the page where the chart is displayed.

Is this feasible?

EDIT: Below an image create in Photoshop which shows what I would like to have in the end - the line shouldn't appear when the chart initially loads, but should be added with a checkbox located in the body of the page using Javascript:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean just plain line (SVG line) or line type chart?

Comment: Sorry I didn't clarify, I meant a line type chart (a curve) with a series of data points

Comment: Ok, so what do you mean by "add another line on top of the heatmap"? Should there be a line chart above the entire heatmap or should it be in the tooltip?

Comment: The line chart should be displayed on the same set of axis as the heatmap, sharing the same coordinates but it should be controlled by a checkbox that turns it on and off located in the HTML of the page, not in the legend of the chart, which we do not display

Comment: Essentially something like it's done here: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/combining-chart-types but with one heatmap and one spline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to combine two series, just add another one to the series array, and to make it appear dynamically using the button, you can first hide it in the settings `series.visible: false` and use the `series.setVisible()` method to toggle the visibility:

```js
const chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
  ...
  series: [{
    type: 'heatmap',
    ...
  }, {
    type: 'spline',
    color: '#0093ff',
    data: [0, 2.5, 2, 4, 5],
    lineWidth: 3,
    visible: false
  }]
});

document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
    chart.series[1].setVisible();
})
```

**Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/j0zbv7y2/ 
**API**: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.visible 
https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#setVisible

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know you could mix heatmaps with other chart this way - I thought it could only be done with non-heatmap charts!

Answer (score 1):

You can add logic to point.events.click() that will create a separate graph positioned relative to the point:

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  ...
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      point: {
        events: {
          click: function() {
            const point = this,
              chart = point.series.chart;

            if (chart.innerChart) {
              chart.innerChart.div.remove();
              chart.innerChart.destroy();
            }

            const id = `point-${this.x}-${this.y}`,
              shape = point.shapeArgs,
              width = shape.width,
              height = shape.height,
              left = chart.plotLeft + point.plotX - width / 2,
              top = chart.plotTop + point.plotY - height / 2,
              chartDiv = document.createElement('div');

            chartDiv.setAttribute("id", id);
            chartDiv.style.cssText = `
                background-color: red;
                position: absolute;
                top: ${top}px;
                left: ${left}px;
                width: ${width}px;
                height: ${height}px;
                zIndex: 10;
            `;

            chart.container.style.position = 'relative';
            chart.container.appendChild(chartDiv);

            chart.innerChart = Highcharts.chart(chartDiv, {
              title: {
                text: point.value
              },
              exporting: {
                enabled: false
              },
              legend: {
                enabled: false
              },
              credits: {
                enabled: false
              },
              series: [{
                data: [1, 3, 7]
              }]
            });
            
            chartDiv.addEventListener('click', function() {
                chartDiv.remove();
                chart.innerChart.destroy();
                delete chart.innerChart;
            })

            chart.innerChart.div = chartDiv;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

**Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/b0xwr59d/

Comment: Hi Michal, 
thanks for taking the time to build this demo - this replaces a single cell with a line chart, but I need the line chart to appear on top of the entire heatmap covering the entire range of XY coordinates - is it possible?. I have added an image prepared in Photoshop to my original question to show more or less what I want to make

Comment: I added another answer because the question is so universal that maybe a person looking for a similar solution to the first one may come across this topic, so it's a pity to delete this answer. The next one is what you're looking for 